# traceback error with functions

Tags: python-2.7

I was just creating acronym for a sentence using python. Can somebody tell me whats wrong with this piece of code? Somewhere I found in python `2.7` input is taken as an expression while its string in `raw_input()` but thats doesn't seem like the issue here:

```
#in my humble opinion
#imho

def first(sent):
  if len(sent) <= 1:
  return sent
elif sent[0] == ' ':
  return first(sent[1:])
else:
  return sent[0] + first(nextWord(sent[1:]))

def nextWord(sentcopy):
    if sentcopy[0] == ' ':
return sentcopy[1:]
else: 
    return nextWord[1:] 

print("Enter the sentence")
sent = raw_input()
acro = first(sent)
print acro
```

Answer (score 0):

if i may suggest another approach:

```
def acro(string):

  return "".join([x[0] for x in string.split(' ') if x])

print(acro(raw_input()))
```